# Combine duplicate rows and sum the values using dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table as shown below,based on yellow highlighted column i need to sum green highlighted columns.

[image]

Expected output is here:

[image]

I have done it using the below code …

```
Sub test()
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("A2:A" & lrow)

    For Each cell In Rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            a = cell
            b = cell.Offset(0, 1)
            c = cell.Offset(0, 5)
            r = cell.Row

            cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell)
            d = 0
            For i = 1 To cnt
                If Cells(r + i, 1) = a And Cells(r + i, 2) = b And Cells(r + i, 6) Then
                Cells(r, 7) = Cells(r + i, 7) + Cells(r, 7)
                Cells(r, 8) = Cells(r + i, 8) + Cells(r, 8)
                d = d + 1
                End If
            Next
            If d > 0 Then Range(Cells(r + 1, 1).Address, Cells(r + d, 1).Address).EntireRow.Delete                
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to do it using scripting dictionary, which is new for me. Since I'm a beginner, I'm unable to modify the below example code found in net!!

Got it from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1021341-vba-merge-duplicate-rows-sum-values-certain-column.html)

```
Sub MG02Sep59()
    Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long, nRng As Range
    Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
            .Add Dn.Value, Dn
        Else
            If nRng Is Nothing Then Set nRng = Dn Else Set nRng = Union(nRng, Dn)
            .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 3) = .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 3) + Dn.Offset(, 3)
        End If
    Next
    If Not nRng Is Nothing Then nRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me out? with some notes if possible.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Consider using a pivot table.

Comment: @jsheeran, i need to do it using VBA. Thank you!

Comment: @Linga Then please be more specific in your question. Where did you get errors? What is wrong with your code? Where did you have difficulties? Just posting your code and hoping us to fix it for you is unlikely to work here on Stack Overflow (see [ask]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how I would do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, ConcatenateStr As String, Sum1 As Currency, Sum2 As Currency
    Dim DictSum1 As Scripting.Dictionary 'You need the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference for this to work
    Dim DictSum2 As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName") 'Change this to fit your sheet name
    Set DictSum1 = New Scripting.Dictionary 'This is how you initialize your dictionary
    Set DictSum2 = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'Store everything on your sheet into the array
    arrData = ws.UsedRange.Value 'this will get from A1 till ctrl+end cell I'd delete rows and columns that are blank

    'Loop through the array to fill the dictionary
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData) '2 because row 1 are headers, UBound is the function to get the last item of your array like .count
        If arrData(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'this will end the loop once finding an empty value on column A
        ConcatenateStr = arrData(i, 1) & arrData(i, 2) & arrData(i, 3) & arrData(i, 6) 'this is to work cleaner, each number is the number of the column concatenated
        Sum1 = arrData(i, 7) 'column Sum 1
        Sum2 = arrData(i, 8) 'column Sum 2
        If Not DictSum1.Exists(ConcatenateStr) Then 'For the column Sum 1
            DictSum1.Add ConcatenateStr, Sum1 'this will add the first item Key = Concatenate String and item = the money value
        Else
            DictSum1(ConcatenateStr) = DictSum1(ConcatenateStr) + Sum1 'this will sum the existing value on the dictionary + the current value of the loop
        End If

        If Not DictSum2.Exists(ConcatenateStr) Then 'For the column Sum 2
            DictSum2.Add ConcatenateStr, Sum2 'this will add the first item Key = Concatenate String and item = the money value
        Else
            DictSum2(ConcatenateStr) = DictSum2(ConcatenateStr) + Sum2 'this will sum the existing value on the dictionary + the current value of the loop
        End If
    Next i

    Erase arrData

    With ws
        .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 6), Header:=xlYes 'Again UsedRange will take everything, Columns as you can see are the ones highlighted in yellow
        arrData = .UsedRange.Value 'Store the results of deleting all the duplicates
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)  'Lets fill the array with the sums
            ConcatenateStr = arrData(i, 1) & arrData(i, 2) & arrData(i, 3) & arrData(i, 6)
            arrData(i, 8) = DictSum1(ConcatenateStr)
            arrData(i, 9) = DictSum2(ConcatenateStr)
        Next i
        .UsedRange.Value = arrData 'Paste back the array with all the sums
    End With

End Sub
```

I've commented the code, but to learn more about dictionaries check this awesome [tutorial](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! im getting run time error 9 here arrData(i, 9) = DictSum2(ConcatenateStr).. Im working on it and wll take time lol!!

Comment: That means `DictSum2(ConcatenateStr)` is empty look for the `ConcatenateStr` if it exists, shouldn't be empty unless it had no data...

Comment: Na its not empty  i have changed  arrData(i, 8) = DictSum1(ConcatenateStr),  arrData(i, 9) = DictSum2(ConcatenateStr)  to (i, 7) and (i, 8 ) and its working now.. Thank you so much again for teaching!!

Comment: Not at all a problem!